# Decode error - output not utf-8

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext

Estoy utilizando ***Sublime Text 2.0.2*** para mis trabajos en Python 3. Me presenta un error al correrlo:

> "Decode error - output not utf-8"

Lo extraño es que al correrlo en el Shell de Python corre sin problemas.

**codigo_ejemplo.py:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

print ("Un texto con una \ttabulación")
```

Answer (score 1):

Recién acabo de encontrar la respuesta y la comparto para quienes se toparon con éste mismo problema.

En la barra de Sublime Text ir a "Preferences", "Browse Packages", luego a \Sublime Text 2\Packages\Python\Python.sublime-build en el disco que se encuentre instalado, agregar una coma y la siguiente línea:

"encoding": "cp1252"

De modo que al final veremos esto:

{
    "cmd": ["python", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "encoding": "cp1252"
}

Guardar los cambios, cerrar Sublime Text, volverlo abrir y todo volverá a funcionar.

Saludos!